# CoreData fetch request with predicate returns 0 records despite records being in table

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Tearing my hair out on this issue:

Doing simple request with one "where" parameter in code.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: FPEstServiceGroupData.entityName)
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "jobID == \(jobID)")
let list = try? moc.fetch(request)
```

Getting 0 records back:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZJOBID, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSERVICEGROUPID, t0.ZSORTORDER, t0.ZJOB FROM ZFPESTSERVICEGROUPDATA t0 WHERE  t0.ZJOBID = ? 
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 59
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x60400028fc30> on entity 'FPEstServiceGroupData' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZJOBID, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSERVICEGROUPID, t0.ZSORTORDER, t0.ZJOB FROM ZFPESTSERVICEGROUPDATA t0 WHERE  t0.ZJOBID = ? ' returned 0 rows with values: (
)
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0004s for 0 rows.
```

At the same time, having located CoreData mySQL file on disk, executing the same request - data is returned:

```
echo "SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZJOBID, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSERVICEGROUPID, t0.ZSORTORDER, t0.ZJOB FROM ZFPESTSERVICEGROUPDATA t0 WHERE  t0.ZJOBID = 59;" | sqlite3 FPData.sqlite
0|43|2|59|Design and Production|255|3|
0|44|2|59|Specification and Concept|254|2|
0|45|2|59|Web Design|256|3|
```

How can it be?

Comment: Sure you have the right file? Every simulator type has its own file space.

Comment: I print out the path to CoreData on app start so I'm 99% sure ;)

Comment: Currently I think the problem is that I am using CoreData in non-main-thread in first case. Investigating now ...